# need to implement Git backup mechanism?

Tags: git, shell, gitolite, bitbucket-server

I have unique situation. where i have around 30 repositories in one git server and every day development is going on. For better disaster management, i want to take backup of 30 repositories every day and thinking to push every day changes to new server ( which is outside of my network/ remote location ).

### Is there any automated way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: That's one reason why my central repository is still a subversion repository: you can put an arbitrary number of projects into it, whereas git is optimized for one project per repo. Additionally, it has a global, serial version and allows me to make incremental dumps/backups based on that version number -- all your repositories get backed up offsite using a few lines in your post-commit hook. You can even backup the raw repository file-by-file, and by telling rsync never to touch already transferred files you can protect against silent data corruption of your backup data.

Answer (score 3):

A standard approach is to keep the repos cloned offsite, and keep them up to date using cron (running 'git fetch --all' or 'git remote update' on each one). This is incremental and can be run very often (hourly, daily, etc).

This doesn't protect you from human error, e.g a bad 'git push --force' that can nuke revisions from the source repo. For that case you probably want periodic static updates - after updating the cloned repo, save it to a bundle using:

```
git bundle create <filename> --all
```

If you want unique filenames then this could work: (put your paths and repo name here, of course)

```
reponame=myrepo
filename=/opt/backups/git-${reponame}-$(date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S).bundle
git bundle create "$filename" --all
```

Then either save the bundles on the machine's local disk or upload somehere else, e.g to S3.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new repo on a remote location, and mirror them.
Then add that to your hooks, or make a script that will push into the mirror.

I do that actually between github and gitlab all the time.

[In this answer you can get a better idea of what i'm saying.](https://serverfault.com/questions/531931/mirror-github-to-gitlab)